# JSON deserialize a series of objects inside brakets {}

Tags: java, json

I am writing a Java Library Parser for Alpha Vantage. Here is the endpoint to download some data:

https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=DIGITAL_CURRENCY_INTRADAY&symbol=BTC&market=CNY&apikey=demo

As you can see the historical data are enclosed into { } and not into []. Do you have any idea to deserialize this? I am using Gson but I cannot find any way

Comment: I don't feel like clicking on unknown links. :) You should post the sample json here. But even before you do... you should make sure you understand the difference between {} and [], if you don't already. I'm not familiar with Gson, but I would be shocked if it didn't know how to deserialize JSON objects.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your JSON structure is probably not what you want it to be. The content of the "Time Series (Digital Currency Intraday)" is an object with properties that seem to represent date. This is annoying from the start, since they are dynamically generated. It would be really simple, if the content would be a list of objects(that could also contain the date value):

```
{
    "Time Series (Digital Currency Intraday)": [
        {
            "date": "2017-10-24 22:30:00",
            "1a. price (CNY)": "34889.57919003",
            "1b. price (USD)": "5259.23870358",
            "2. volume": "5708.68994668",
            "3. market cap (USD)": "30023363.11434300"
        }
    ]
}
```

This would be a better structure, imo. Then all you need to do is change the property names to be more Java friendly and create some POJOs, then you could deserialize with GSON easily. See: http://www.baeldung.com/gson-deserialization-guide

As for a solution with the current structure, you could maybe make use of the entitySet() method of the JSONObject.

It returns a Set> object. Assuming you would use the method on an object representing the root Json object, the String values that you would get in the Map objects would be "Meta Data" and "Time Series (Digital Currency Intraday)". These are the properties of the root object in your JSON. And the JsonElement they are associated with, would be the value of the property, in this case another JSON object.

So you can use this and your knowledge of how the JSON is structured, to deserialize the data to some objects of a class. WIth a couple of loops, of course.